# rails get entire current url but change the http protocol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, parameters, request

i need to create a link in my rails view that basically takes the user from the normal http page to the same page but using https.

i currently have something like

```
 <a href="https://<%= request.env['HTTP_HOST']%><%= request.path %>">CLICK ME!</a>
```

however it:

- does not include the parameter string
- just looks hack-ish to me

is there a better way to take the user from http to the same relative request path with all of the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
<%= link_to "CLICK ME!", named_url(protocol: 'https') %>
```

Where named_url is the route to whatever you want to link to.

**EDIT**

Since you don't have a named route and just want to use whatever page the user is on, you can do something like:

```
<%= link_to "CLICK ME!", "https://#{request.host}#{request.fullpath}" %>
```

You can find more about the `request` object here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object

Comment: that's the problem: i don't have a `named_url` - it should always be the same full url (plus parameters) as the current page that the user is on.